# MVC Controller Redirect To Jquery Tab

Tags: model-view-controller, jquery-ui, controller, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a controller in MVC that after successful create command needs to redirect the view to a contact tab made by jquery. Here is what I have for controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Contact newContact, int id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                gogoDB.AddToContacts(newContact); 
                gogoDB.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index" + "/" + id, "Client");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(newContact);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(newContact);
        }
```

The url I am trying to redirect to is

```
http://localhost:xxxxx/Client/Index/2#contacts
```

Current code ReturnToAction("Index" + "/" + id, Client") redirects to

```
http://localhost:xxxxx/Client/Index/2
```

which is not what I want. I have also tried Redirect("Client/Index/" + id + "#contacts") but the url I get is something like this:

```
http://localhost:xxxxx/Contact/Create/Client/Index/2#contacts
```

As you can see, the problem is that I am calling a page generated with client controller from inside the contact controller. Id works right in all examples.

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried using a return RedirectPermanent() and hard-coding the tab's URL?

Comment: Hard coding won't work because the return url has a dynamically generated id in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do something like that.

**View**

```
 $('#SpecificRedirectTest').click(function() {
window.location="/Controller/Index?Id="+ $('myId').val() +"&redirect2Tab=true";
  });
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index (int Id ,  bool? redirect2Tab)
{
  var client = this._myService.GetById (Id);
  var fvm = this.EditClientFormViewModel (client, MyTabs.EditTab);

if (redirect2Tab.HasValue) {
  if (redirect2Tab.Value) {
    fvm = this.EditClientFormViewModel  (client, MyTabs.SalesHistoryTab);
  }
}
return View("ViewEdit", fvm);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Koi, but we took a step away from partial views so I cant test the solution as we are no longer using them.